# Django/Bootstrap - How do I limit blocks per row?

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I have a page with a bootstrap card for every item like

{% for item in item %} create a card with some content....

How do I limit the amount of cards created per row until it jumps to the row below it?

```
 <div class = 'card-group'>
{% for plant in plant%}
{% if plant.available%}
<div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3" style=''>
  <img style='height: auto; max-width: 100%;' src="{{plant.thumbnail}}" alt="...">
  <div class="container">
    <h4 style='color:white;' class="card-title"><b>{{plant.name |title}}</b></h4>
    <p style='font-size: 20px'>Soil: {{plant.soil |title}}</p>
    <p style='font-size: 20px'>Price per unit: £{{plant.price |title}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class='button-section'>
  <button class="order-button"><a href=''>Order Online</a></button>
  </div>
</div>

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

This is the css applied at the moment

```
.card {
    margin: 10px;
    display: flex;
}

.card-group {
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.card-title {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.card-text,
.card-title {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.card-body {
    text-align: left;
}

.card-button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 3px solid #ff7505;
    color: rgb(255, 254, 254);
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.card-button:hover {
    background-color: #f75c02;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I want to display only 4 objects per row, then jump to next row and so on...

Comment: Please show the template code, elaborate what html elements you generate and which styles apply to them.

Comment: Since the number of div elements is dynamic, using bootstrap's grid will be tricky. CSS grid is probably a better fit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this did it for me

```
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4 g-4">
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap rows have 12 columns each. If you set your div at col-4 then your for loop will print 3 columns per row. 4x3=12. If you did col-2 then you will get 6 smaller divs per row. 6x2=12

Comment: That answer is too abrupt. Anyone who doesn't know bootstrap very well won't know what you are talking about. Give some context / explanation, add an example so that your answer is more understandable. That way your answer would be more likely to be accepted and get upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forloop.counter` and template tag `divisibleby`. Then code can be something like:

```html
{% for item in items %}

  {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"4" %}
    <div class="row">
  {% endif %}

  {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"4" %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Or you can implement that logic inside views. Can looks like this:

```py
rows = []
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  # Item.objects.all() etc.
per_row = 4

i = 0
while True:
    row_items = items[i * per_row : (i + 1) * per_row]
    if not row_items:
        break
    rows.append(row_items)
    i += 1
print(rows)
```

When you run that sample about the output is `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9]]` so you have nested lists so you have to you two for loops in the template.